# LED reverse voltage rating

Tags: voltage, led, reverse-polarity

I am looking at an LED and trying to understand the Reverse Voltage parameter because it doesn't make sense to anything I test on the bench.  Pretty much every LED you find will specify a Reverse Voltage (Vrev) as 5V.  However, I'm finding that I can easily apply as much as 20V and it will still work fine after the fact.

For reference:

[image]

My experiment was to set up an LED in LED1 configuration and it stayed off as expected, and then I connected it in LED2 configuration and it turned on without a problem.  I would expect 20V to WAY exceed the 5V rating, but it seems to be fine.  Am I misunderstanding the Vrev parameter?  General purpose diodes like the 1N4007 have reverse voltage ratings in the range of 500V and up.  Here is a part datasheet for reference.
https://www.lumex.com/spec/SSI-LXR4815GD-150.pdf

Comment: 5V is listed as the minimum, so measuring 20V is consistent with the spec sheet value.

Comment: @user263983 See the datasheet linked by Punchki in his question above.

Comment: @user263983 I think you have misunderstood me. The datasheet shows a 5V minimum voltage, so measuring a higher voltage is consistent with spec.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that you can't know if the LED is fine even if you say so. You might have shaved years off out of the useful life, or made it slightly dimmer.

The reverse voltage parameter, at least on your LED data sheet, is not an absolute maximum rating. It's just under the normal electrical specifications. It does not mean the LED will immdiately blow up at 5.001V reverse voltage.

The electrical specs simply state that at least 5V or more is required to reach the 100uA reverse leakage current testing condition. So 100uA is guaranteed to be never reached when voltage is kept below 5V.

What the datasheet fails to mention is, why the 100 uA test condition is chosen, will it not degrade at all below that limit, or some amount but by how much and in which way. It also does not mention any maximum voltage. It might be that even in your experiment, the 100 uA current was not reached with 20V reverse voltage.

Which of course is not very important, as typically a good design would not allow reverse voltage to go above 5V, but there are also cheap designs where e.g. mains AC is used for LED and there is no reverse voltage protection, so there can be more than 325V reverse voltage over LED and they might work for a long time.

Comment: "there can be more than 325V reverse voltage over LED and they might work for a long time" - Are you sure? I've seen some LEDs which can survive 50-60V in reverse, but above ~120V all LEDs I have seen start conducting and inevitably die. Even a few mA in reverse result in irreversible brightness loss.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases data sheet values are selected for ease of testing and to obtain the best compromise between testing fall-out and the required user functionality.

A 5V reverse rating is adequate for the majority of applications that subject LEDs to reverse voltages; eg multiplexed LED arrays.

As other answers have mentioned there are some applications that are limited by reverse voltage rating but even those applications are easily arranged to avoid high reverse voltages.

For example a low-cost conventional diode in antiparallel with the LED will avoid high voltages in the reverse direction for mains AC driven LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

5v is guaranteed performance. if you get 20V you are lucky, the next batch of that part number may fail at 6V